# What is the correct way to determine daily Kwh value from a series of Kw readings (kw value at time) in the database

Tags: c#, sql, math, physics

I have a device which reads kw values off electrical devices to measure their (rate of consumption of energy) at a certain time. these values are then sent to a poller (which periodically asks the device for the values), and inserted into a database.

Example:

```
1st reading - 10 kw at 1.01pm
2nd reading - 15 kw at 1.23pm
3rd reading - 11 kw at 1.30pm
```

As you can see, the polling interval is not fixed, so the values can be inserted into the database at different times. for simplicity, we can just imagine the database is just a table with 2 columns, [time] and [kw_value].

This is actually a two part question:

1. How do I get the daily kwh value from these readings (energy consumption for the whole day)? I'm pretty bad in mathematics so I dont know what is the right way to get a daily kwh value from these values.

   I thought of adding up all the values and getting the average, but my mom says that I should plot out a graph of all readings for the whole day, and then get the area below the plotted line (sort of like getting the integral of the graph), which will then give me the total power consumed for the day. I should then use this value to divide by the duration for the whole day in hours to get the kwh, is that right?
2. How do I do this using the database? if there are thousands of readings in a day (from multiple electrical devices,in this case we have 3 columns - [time],[kw_value],[deviceid]), how should I calculate this, should I load up all the values in memory (i'm using C#) and calculate from there or can I use SQL to calculate this?

Edit:
Thanks guys for pointing out the difference between kw and kwh. i made a big mistake with my original question, hence this edit. just to reiterate, the device reads kw values (rate of energy consumption in kilo joules/sec) at a particular time, and given a list / plot of these values in the database, what's the correct way to determine the kwh (total energy consumed) for a given day.

Comment: *What is the most efficient way to ...* leads almost ever to a closed question because the answer will never be definitive since there will always be a more efficient way. And that does not fit a Q&A site that expects answerable questions.

Comment: What does the database table look like? Please post the `CREATE TABLE` for it.

Comment: Your mom is right!!, we need to multiply width with the value.

Comment: What kind of database are you using?

Comment: Is that kwh value the number of kilowatt hours used during that period (that is, the device used 11 kwh in the 7 minutes between the 2nd and 3rd readings), or is it drawing 11 kw at the instant it's polled? Also, are the devices used fairly evenly throughout the 24-hour period (that is, use is about the same at 2 PM, 8 PM, and 3 AM)?

Comment: Power consumption at a certain time is not measured in kwh but kw. The result you are looking for should be given in kwh, isn't it? Which db system do you use? The solution will require advanced sql if it should be calculated on the database and that's most probably dependent on the sql dialect.

Comment: hi horse, the create table for my Ms Sql database is like this

CREATE TABLE kwh_poll
(
Id int identity (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[time] datetime,
kwh_value decimal,
deviceid varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)

Thanks for reading

Comment: hi Csharper sorry i made a mistake, i'll re-edit the question. the reading is in kwh

Comment: hi Andomar i'm using MSSQL. thanks

Comment: hi Jim Mischel, the reading is the kwh value calculated by the device at that time (it does not relate the value with a previous reading). the devices may be turned off at certain times of the day so they are not used fairly evenly. thanks

Comment: So then it's not a kwh value, but rather a kw value? This is a very important distinction. kwh is the amount of power used over a period of time. kw is the amount of power being drawn at an instant in time.

Comment: @Rotem: You are wrong. Consumption at any given instant is measure in Watts (or joules/second).

Comment: Both power measurements are possible: You can measure the energy consumed in kWh since the last measurement. Or you can measure the average power consumption per time period in Watts. In Germany, most meters measure the accumulated energy in kWh. Meters for big customers show the energy per quarter of an hour.

Comment: I don't understand you example. Electricity meters usually show kWh since the beginning. But if that was the case, each value would be at least as big as the previous one. Do you mean that the value you're getting is kWh *since the previous measurement*?

Comment: First of all kWh is not power, it's energy. kW is power as HP is power (I see no time units in the horsepower of a car). Power applied in a time interval is energy, thus kWh is a energy unit that establishes the average power applied during the specified interval. This means that 10 kWh is the same as saying that you are consuming 10 kW of power during one hour. So if you are consuming 10 Kw in a 15 minute timespan, it is equivalent to saying you have consumed 2.5 kWh.

Comment: hi Jim Mischel, sorry for replying late. Yes you are right, i made a very bad mistake (confusing kwh with kw) i'll re-edit the question again. it is a Kw reading, and i'm supposed to compute the kwh for a given period of time using the kw readings. With reference to the comment above to Csharper, the reading should be in Kw. Sorry guys, thanks for pointing out the difference between kw and kwh, i went to http://www.energylens.com/articles/kw-and-kwh and learnt the big difference after watching your comments.

Comment: hi inbetween, yeah thanks for pointing out the diffrence between kw and kwh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're certainly not going to get an exact kWh value. With such an infrequent polling frequency, you could end up with very large differences between estimated and actual usage. You give this example:

```
1st reading - 10 kW at 1.01pm
2nd reading - 15 kW at 1.23pm
3rd reading - 11 kW at 1.30pm
```

Given no other information, about the only reasonable thing to do is to average each pair of readings and multiple that by the time. From 1.01 to 1.23 is 22 minutes, or .367 hours. The average reading over that period is (10 + 15)/2, or 12.5 kW, giving an estimated usage of (12.5 * 0.367), or 4.58 kWh.

There are some obvious holes in that approach, though. What happens if the *actual* consumption were:

```
10 kW at 1.01pm
 0 kW at 1.02pm // machine turned off
15 kW at 1.23pm // machine turned back on
11 kW at 1.29pm
```

Your actual usage for the period between 1.01 and 1.23 is 10 kW for one minute, or 0.16 kWh.

The numbers could be off by a similar amount in the other direction. That is, your calculations could be very low than very high.

If that is reasonable, the way I would do it is to make a SQL query that returns the data ordered by machine and then by time. So you get:

```
machine1, 1.01 am, reading
machine1, 1.20 am, reading
... etc. ...
machine2, 1.03, reading
machine2, 2.15, reading
```

So all of machine 1's readings are presented to you in time order, then machine 2, etc.

You can certainly write a query using ORDER BY and GROUP BY to return you all of the readings in the proper order. You could then use a `SqlDataReader` to move sequentially through the results, computing the consumption for each period (using the average calculation shown above), and summing the results for each machine. I don't know SQL well enough to say if it's possible to write a query that would do all of the calculation for you and return a result set that had, for example:

```
machine1, start time, end time, total power consumed
machine2, start time, end time, total power consumed
etc
```

Answer (score 1):

This query looks up a previous row for each row.  Then for each interval, it assumes the entire interval had the kwh value from the start.

```
; with  numbered as 
        (
        select  *
        ,       row_number() over (partition by deviceid order by time) rn
        from    YourTable
        )
select  deviceid
,       sum(t0.kwh_value * datediff(s, t0.[time], t1.[time])/3600)
from    numbered t1
join    numbered t0
on      t1.deviceid = t0.deviceid
        and t1.rn = t0.rn + 1
group by
        deviceid
```

You can modify the query to calculate the use the average kwh for the interval:

```
,       sum((t1.kwh_value + t0.kwh_value)/2 * datediff(s, t0.[time], t1.[time])/3600)
```

Comment: If they interval between two measurements spans across midnight, you have to caclulate which portion of the measured energy belongs to the current day.

Comment: Doesn't really matter. If you assign the whole measurement to one day, it will be missing for the other. The sum of the two will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

My solution tries to handle to overlaps of day intervals and measuring intervals:

```
public class Measurement
        {
            public DateTime t;
            public double kwh;

            public Measurement(string t, double kwh)
            {
                this.t = DateTime.Parse(t);
                this.kwh = kwh;
            }
        }

        public static double getPowerConsumption(IEnumerable<Measurement> measurements, DateTime day)
        {
            DateTime never = DateTime.MinValue;
            DateTime tomorrow = day.AddDays(1);
            DateTime prev = never;
            double kwh = 0;

            foreach (Measurement m in measurements)
            {
                if (m.t >= day)
                //  measurement in our after or day
                {
                    if (m.t >= tomorrow)
                    {
                        if ((prev != never) && (prev < m.t))
                        {
                            //  add portion up to midnight
                            kwh += m.kwh * (tomorrow.Ticks - prev.Ticks) / (double)(m.t.Ticks - prev.Ticks);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    else if ((prev != never) && (prev < day) && (prev < m.t))
                    {
                        kwh += m.kwh * (m.t.Ticks - day.Ticks) / (double)(m.t.Ticks - prev.Ticks);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        kwh += m.kwh;
                    }
                }
                prev = m.t;
            }

            return kwh;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime myDay = new DateTime(2012, 11, 2);
            List<Measurement> measurements = new List<Measurement>() { new Measurement("01.11.2012 23:30", 10), 
                                                                       new Measurement("02.11.2012 10:00", 1), 
                                                                       new Measurement("02.11.2012 23:30", 5), 
                                                                       new Measurement("03.11.2012 10:00", 6) };
            double kwh = getPowerConsumption(measurements, myDay);

            Console.WriteLine("Powerconsumption for " + myDay.ToShortDateString() + " was " + kwh.ToString("#.##") + "kWh");
        }
```